# What are some situations when normalizing input data to zero mean, unit variance is not appropriate or not beneficial?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-scaling, normalization

I have seen normalization of input data to zero mean, unit variance many times in machine learning. Is this a good practice to be done all the time or are there times when it is not appropriate or not beneficial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A detailed answer to the question can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189652/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-scale-normalize-data-for-machine-learning).

> [...]are there times when it is not appropriate or not beneficial?

Short answer: Yes and No. *Yes* in the terms, that it can significantly change your output of e.g. clustering algorithms. *No*, on the other hand, if these changes are what you want to achieve. Or to put it in the words of the author of the mentioned source:

> Scaling features for clustering algorithms can substantially change the outcome. Imagine four clusters around the origin, each one in a different quadrant, all nicely scaled. Now, imagine the y-axis being stretched to ten times the length of the the x-axis. instead of four little quadrant-clusters, you're going to get the long squashed baguette of data chopped into four pieces along its length! (And, the important part is, you might prefer either of these!)

The take-home-message of this is: always think carefully about what you want to achieve and what kind of data your algorithms prefer - it **does** matter!

Comment: **PCA** would, by the way, be one of the algorithms that do not want to be operated without normalization - just to highlight the other side of the story.